# Xcode 4.3.1: Doesn't show me line of code when: Terminating app due to uncaught exception

Tags: xcode

In previous versions of Xcode, when I ran into a crash (does not respond to selector, or array index out of bounds, etc) Xcode would usually open the file where the crash happened and often take me to the line where it crashed. The latest Xcode doesn't seem to be doing that which is making debugging a LOT harder.

Do I need to enable some new settings or something? I just downloaded the latest version 4.3.1 and I created a new project so the project settings should hopefully be the right defaults.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try this: http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

Summary: it can be helpful to add an exception breakpoint, which breaks when an exception is thrown, rather than when it is caught. In order to do this, go to the breakpoint navigator pane, click on the `+` in the bottom left corner, choose "Exception Breakpoint" from the popup menu, and accept the default settings. Note: despite being an old tip, this still works on Xcode 8 in late 2016.